# Null Exception при попытки модификации обьекта класса Java

Tags: java, ооп

При попытке модификации полей класса выдает Null Exception. Собственно код. Ошибку выдает при вызове метода Create

Основной класс

```
    public class Dealership implements CRUD {
     private Car car;
     private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
     public Dealership() {}
     @Override
     public void Create() {
     this.cars.add(car.Modify(car));

     }
     @Override
    public void GetById(int id) {
    for(int i=0;i<this.cars.size();i++) {
        if(cars.get(i).getId()==id) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Id: "+cars.get(i).getId()+" Model: "+cars.get(i).getModel()+
                    " Dealer: "+cars.get(i).getDealer()+"Speed: "+cars.get(i).getSpeed()+"\n");     }
        }
     }
    @Override
    public void  GetByModel(String model) {
        for(int i=0;i<this.cars.size();i++) {
            if(cars.get(i).getModel()==model) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Id: "+cars.get(i).getId()+" Model: "+cars.get(i).getModel()+
                        " Dealer: "+cars.get(i).getDealer()+"Speed: "+cars.get(i).getSpeed()+"\n");
            }
        }
       }
      @Override
     public void  GetByDealer(String dealer) {

        for(int i=0;i<this.cars.size();i++) {
            if(cars.get(i).getDealer()==dealer) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Id: "+cars.get(i).getId()+" Model: "+cars.get(i).getModel()+
                        " Dealer: "+cars.get(i).getDealer()+"Speed: "+cars.get(i).getSpeed()+"\n"); 
            }
         }


          }
               @Override
      public void  GetByMaxSpeedLimit(double speed) {
        for(int i=0;i<this.cars.size();i++) {
            if(cars.get(i).getSpeed()>speed) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Id: "+cars.get(i).getId()+" Model: "+cars.get(i).getModel()+
                        " Dealer: "+cars.get(i).getDealer()+"Speed: "+cars.get(i).getSpeed()+"\n");          }
        }
    }

   }
```

Наследник:

```
    public class Car extends Dealership implements CCRUD{
    private int id;
    private String model;
    private String dealer;
    private double speed;

    public Car() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.model = "None";
        this.dealer = "None";
        this.speed = 0;
    }
    @Override
    public Car Modify(Car c) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    id = in.nextInt();  
    model = in.nextLine();
    dealer = in.nextLine();
    speed = in.nextDouble();

    in.close();
    return c;
    }
    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    @Override
    public String getModel() {
        return this.model;
    }
    @Override
    public String getDealer() {
        return this.dealer;
    }
    @Override
    public double getSpeed() {
        return this.speed;
    }

}
```

Comment: Пройдитесь отладчиком и посмотрите почему в `this.cars.add(car.Modify(car));` приходит null

Comment: @dmtr после входа сразу кидает на private void dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
        getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(this, e);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В методе `Create()` вы вызываете метод `this.cars.add(car.Modify(car));`. В `car.Modify(car)` вы пытаетесь передать ссылку, определенную выше `private Car car;`.

NPE возникает, потому что `private Car car;` не содержит ссылки на объект, вы передаете пустую ссылку. Нужно создать экземпляр объекта и присвоить его этой ссылке, например через оператор `new`.